# Can't trigger a touchstart / click event on safari / iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, click

I have read as many posts here on SO as I could find but nothing seems to be working for me.

Everything I've tried works on all desktop browsers but not on Safari on `iOS` - it is just refusing to have any of it. I'm trying to call a `click` or `touchstart` event on a play/pause button after an audio element has been loaded (by a real user click) and I just can't get it to happen. I know it's not happening as despite playback not starting, a click / touch event on the element I'm targeting switches the icon in the button and this is not happening.

Things I've tried, all of which were called inside a `setTimeout` with super generous delays (5 seconds +) just in case it was firing before the player was loaded - but aside from the audio aspect that's irrelevant to why the element isn't reacting like it's been clicked or touched :

```
var e = new Event('touchstart');
document.getElementById('playPauseBtn').dispatchEvent(e);

//
var e2 = new Event('click');
document.getElementById('playPauseBtn').dispatchEvent(e2);

//
document.getElementById('playPauseBtn').click();

// not even sure this is a real function - desperation...
document.getElementById('playPauseBtn').touchstart();

//
function triggerEvent( elem, event ) {
  var clickEvent = new Event( event );
  elem.dispatchEvent( clickEvent ); 
}

var elem = document.getElementById('playPauseBtn');
triggerEvent( elem, 'click' );

// using the same function above
triggerEvent( elem, 'touchstart' );
```

There were a handful of other things I tried also but you get the gist. I think I'm probably approaching this the wrong way for `iOS`. Some advice on how to simulate a user touch event on an `html` element in `iOS` would be appreciated.